# MFP Objective C - WLAFSSLPinningModeCertificate can only be applied on a manager with a secure base URL

Tags: objective-c, ssl-certificate, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

Please help with this, I'm using the latest IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework
When try to login to https server.

> ```
> [[WLAuthorizationManager sharedInstance] login:@"AuthenticateUser" withCredentials:params withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
>             if (error != nil) {
>                 errorHandler(error);
>             }else{
>                 successHandler(nil);
>             }
>         }];
> ```

### Below error message is shown.

> Thread 1: "A security policy configured with
> `WLAFSSLPinningModeCertificate` can only be applied on a manager with
> a secure base URL (i.e. https)"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using certificate pinning with a http URL. If so, the behaviour is indeed expected.

What is the `wlProtocol` in your `mfpclient.plist` ?

If it is http, then the whole point of using certificate pinning is moot since there is no certificate involved in the communication.

Comment: [[WLClient sharedInstance] pinTrustedCertificatePublicKeyFromFile:certPath];
After including this, everything is solved. Thanks for ur replies too.